# Trying to grab multiple fiedld from querydef and transfer to default email

Tags: email, ms-access, pdf, vba

I have been working with a database and received help getting the correct function to occur in that the code is working with a query and then looping through each report group (by name) and populating the fields of a report and saving the report by individual name. The last part of this which I have been struggling with. One of the fields in the recordset is Sup_Email, I’m trying to pass the report for sup with the email address in the above field to my default email client. I can’t figure how to isolate the second variable, keep it together with the right report and pass them both to email. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Private Sub CreateReports_Click()

```
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String
Dim StrSQL
Dim StrEmail
Dim stWhereStr As String 'Where Condition'
Dim stSection As String 'Selection from drop down list
Dim stfile As String


    StrSQL = "SELECT distinct[Sup] FROM ([OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir])"
    StrEmail = "SELECT [Sup_email] FROM ([OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir])"
    y = Year(date)


    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim qdTemp As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdTemp = db.CreateQueryDef("", StrSQL)
    Set rst = qdTemp.OpenRecordset()


    If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
        MsgBox "No data available for the Ledger Process routine."
    Else
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rst.EOF
            x = rst![Sup]
            z = rst![Sup_email]

        stDocName = "Courts - ISSR Recertification Report"
        stWhereStr = "[OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].[SUP]= '" & x & "'"
        stfile = "P:\DFI\FIB\Access Tables\FibCustomers\ISSR Reports\Courts\" & x & " - " & y & " FedInvest InvestOne Recertification.pdf"

        DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , stWhereStr

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, stfile

        DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName

        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
```

End Sub

Each Sup has only one email address. The way it is setup is that a query (the OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir query from above) pulls the first and last name of the supervisor and concatenates it into Sup, it also has their phone and email address (Sup_email), then has the employee, their accounts and access level, this information all applies to each field of the form. The direction I was sent yesterday created a query recordset (it's was continuing to loop). I tried then to add the field for email, and it's all gone awry since.

Comment: Your query is only returning ONE field (SUP). Where are you getting the email address from?

Comment: Then please explain why the code you show above does NOT have that field? I'm trying to help, but need the facts. Please update your code above with EXACTLY what your code looks like.

Comment: Your modified code will not work because you never reference the 'strEmail' SQL string. We need to back up and define the environment. Since both SQL strings reference the same table, I assume your table has a report variable (SUP) and an associated email address? Is it possible there are two emails for the same report? If so, do you send twice or send one email to both addresses?  And if you edit your code again, please add some spaces so it gets formatted properly (i.e. the Sub and Dim's and End Sub are not formatted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code so that it uses the email address from the table and will create the report, then send.

```
Private Sub CreateReports_Click()
Dim x           As String
Dim y           As String
Dim StrSQL      As String
Dim stWhereStr  As String 'Where Condition'
Dim stSection   As String 'Selection from drop down list
Dim stfile      As String
Dim stDocName   As String
Dim StrEmail    As String

StrSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW [OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].[Sup], [OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].SupEmail " & _
    "FROM [OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir];"
y = Year(Date)


Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim qdTemp As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdTemp = db.CreateQueryDef("", StrSQL)
Set rst = qdTemp.OpenRecordset()
If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
    MsgBox "No data available for the Ledger Process routine."
Else
    Debug.Print rst.Fields.Count
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        x = rst![Sup]
        StrEmail = rst![Supemail]

        stDocName = "Courts - ISSR Recertification Report"
        stWhereStr = "[OPDA ISSR- Courts Users by District/Cir].[SUP]= '" & x & "'"
        stfile = "P:\DFI\FIB\Access Tables\FibCustomers\ISSR Reports\Courts\" & x & " - " & y & " FedInvest InvestOne Recertification.pdf"

        DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , stWhereStr
        DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, StrEmail, , , "My Subject here", "your report"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, stfile
        DoCmd.Close acReport, stDocName

        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```